# How can I store two foreign keys from the users table into a second table in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am stuck as I am new to Laravel.

I have a users table and message table and here is my message table schema

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('sender')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('sender')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('reciever')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('reciever')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('msg');
        $table->string('attachment')->nullable();
        $table->string('seen')->default(0);
        $table->integer('deleted')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here `sender` and `reciever` are the both foriegn keys of the user table.

In my app I have access to the `sender` id from Auth::user() and also I have access to `reciever` id.. How can I estublish a relationship and store messages? 
I have been trying in many ways please help. Thank you.

I think my problem is with the relationship. Please have a look and suggest me right way

The User Model

```
public function sender()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'sender');
}

public function reciever()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'reciever');
}
```

The Message Model

```
public function sender()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'sender');
}

public function reciever()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'reciever');
}
```

Comment: You have to define relations in your models. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thank you for the comment and Yes I defined and it seems my relationship definition is not right that's why asking.

Comment: Then please show the code for your relation definitions. I cannot guess why your relations arent working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it like this:

```
// Create message model instance
$message = new App\Message(['msg' => 'Something test', ...]);

// Retrieve the related user
$user = App\User::find(1);

// Call the method you defined in user model
$user->sender()->save($message);
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I have a question if you don't mind. I am inside the message model but even though I have to create in instance like you said $message = new Message($input); I am not being able to understand. Could you explain or point me a blog where I can read about it? Thank you.

Comment: I can't understand what you said. You meant that you did the logic in the message model?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just store bot sender and receiver ids and when you need to retrieve the data you can use an inner join statement.
here is an example of how i did this on my own app

```
$message->user_id = $userid;
$message->message = $msg;
$message->recipient = "user";

$message->save();
```

And when retrieving

```
$msgs = Message::join('users', 'messages.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('messages.*', 'users.name', 'users.image')
        ->where('messages.user_id',$id)
        ->get();
```

In my case i store only one id the other is a string since the messages are always between the admin and users i dont need the admins id

Comment: Add the recipients ID instead of a string like i did.